# SQL Server Importing local Excel spreadsheet using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have to import Excel spreadsheets into a SQL Server database. The Excel spreadsheets are not on a server, but local. How do I import them using stored procedures?

Comment: Do you need to use a stored procedure? Have you considered the Data Import Wizard?

Comment: The SQL Server machine cannot reach onto your local hard disk (and that's a **good thing**!) - so you'll need to copy those Excel files to the server (or a UNC share it can access) as the very first step

Comment: You could try to "reverse" this.  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/sql-server-data-to-a-jet-database/